# Compiled with problems: × ERROR Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron

I have a Typescript project that I'm trying to get packaged into Electron via Webpack.

When I do `npm run start` I get the following errors:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/preload.ts' in '/Users/vino/git/dynasty'

ERROR in ./src/main.ts 26:23-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './gameState.js' in '/Users/vino/git/dynasty/src'

ERROR in ./src/main.ts 27:18-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './game.js' in '/Users/vino/git/dynasty/src'
```

and so on and so forth for every file in the project.

The contents of my `.webpack/renderer/main_window/index.js` contains the processed `main.ts` of my project, but not any of the other source files. Furthermore, the Javascript console complains of not being able to find the stylesheet, the fonts, jquery, or even the main.js.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "dynasty",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Dynasty",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf ./build",
    "build": "tsc -p ./tsconfig-local.json",
    "postbuild": "copyfiles -u 1 src/*.min.js src/index.htm src/style.css art/* art/**/* ./build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^6.4.2",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^1.7.3",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "electron": "^26.2.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.3.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

forge.config.ts

```
import type { ForgeConfig } from '@electron-forge/shared-types';
import { MakerSquirrel } from '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel';
import { MakerZIP } from '@electron-forge/maker-zip';
import { MakerDeb } from '@electron-forge/maker-deb';
import { MakerRpm } from '@electron-forge/maker-rpm';
import { AutoUnpackNativesPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives';
import { WebpackPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-webpack';

import { mainConfig } from './webpack.main.config';
import { rendererConfig } from './webpack.renderer.config';

const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [new MakerSquirrel({}), new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']), new MakerRpm({}), new MakerDeb({})],
  plugins: [
    new AutoUnpackNativesPlugin({}),
    new WebpackPlugin({
      mainConfig,
      renderer: {
        config: rendererConfig,
        entryPoints: [
          {
            html: './src/index.htm',
            js: './src/main.ts',
            name: 'main_window',
            preload: {
              js: './src/preload.ts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

webpack.main.config.ts

```
import type { Configuration } from 'webpack';

import { rules } from './webpack.rules';

export const mainConfig: Configuration = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './src/electron-index.ts',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
};
```

webpack.renderer.config.ts

```
import type { Configuration } from 'webpack';

import { rules } from './webpack.rules';
import { plugins } from './webpack.plugins';

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
});

export const rendererConfig: Configuration = {
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css'],
  },
};
```

webpack.plugins.ts

```
import type IForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin: typeof IForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

export const plugins = [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    logger: 'webpack-infrastructure',
    typescript: {
      configFile: 'tsconfig-webpack.json',
    },
  }),
];
```

webpack.rules.ts

```
import type { ModuleOptions } from 'webpack';
import * as path from 'path';

export const rules: Required<ModuleOptions>['rules'] = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
    // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
    test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
        configFile: path.resolve('./tsconfig-webpack.json'),
      },
    },
  },
];
```